# Prevent jQueryui css from making containing elements larger

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui

I used typical way to create tabs using jQuery UI, by wrapping up asp.net usercontrols as below -

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab1">Schools</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Colleges</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab1">
        <uc:schools id="ucSchools" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <div id="tab2">
        <uc:colleges id="ucColleges" runat="server" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Tabs work awesome, but including jQueyui.css. Made all the contents of the my user control larger, than usual.

```
<link href="jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I do not see any name collision in jqueryui.css with our stylesheet.

If you've encountered this issue, please suggest how to tweak the css to keep containing div size `intact`.

Comment: I think what you are seeing is normal as you are using the jquery-ui styles which adjusts the margins, padding, font size, etc. on the controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which ever `class` you want to have first priority or override then you should use `!important`

### Example:

```
div { 
   color: #ff0000 !important; 
}
```

### UPDATE:

Apart from `!important`, the other way is "Render your link tag after jquery-ui stylesheet link on the page. So your file takes priority and applies to the page".

### Example:

```
<link href="jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: I think jQueryui modified many default values, so it seems I'll have to write explicit styles for all items, lot of work :-(. Is there any workaround, to set jQuery ui styles always less priority.

Comment: @autrevo: Render your custom link tag after jquery-ui stylesheet link tag on the page. So your file takes priority and applies to the page